# NetBeans : giving syntax error in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, netbeans, laravel-5

Following is the snippet of code from Kernel.php in laravel.

```
 protected $middleware = [
            \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        ];
```

Netbeans says

```
Syntax error
     unexpected:    class
     after: ::
     expected:  identifier

POSSIBLE Syntax Error (check preceding valid syntax error)
 unexpected:
```

What's going on ? underline on whole line is irritating me.

Comment: `class` is a reserved word and cannot be used.

Comment: @Charlottte Above code is written on laravel kernel.php. so It's not me who used 'class' in above code. Bt I don't think NetBeans knows that so do YOU know anyway to make netbeans not give underline below \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,

Answer (score 1):

`ClassName::class` is a new feature,
right click on Project Node and change the php version to 5.5 or above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You should change your project properties. Maybe When you created project you choose PHP version lower than 5.5. `Code ClassName::class;` is new feature PHP 5.5

Comment: netbeans project configuration shows php 5.4 only but my version of php is php 5.6

Comment: Click right button Your Netbeans project name and
**Properties** => **Sources** And change **PHP Version** to **PHP 5.6**